# random vector density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider now a vector $X = (X_1, X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are real-valued random variables. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ have densities $f_1$ and $f_2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Show by example that it is possible that $X$ does not have a density.

Comment: Wait a moment, you drastically changed your question with your last edit! Right now, it is **Not** possible to show what you want by the given answer and the answer by @Augustin doesn't fit any longer, please restore the first edit of your question

Comment: I changed it back now. If you want to know what happens in the independent case, please ask a new question or use the search

Answer (score 1):

For example, take $X_1=X_2$ normally distributed. Then $X$ does not have a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^2$.